# Too many boolean expressions in if statement, how to fix that?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to loop and double a number until it got all numbers 0-9 in it, it works but my if statement got many boolean expressions and looks ugly, I've tried to use if('0123456789' in first_num) but doesn't work... Anyone got an idea how to make the if statement more pretty?

```
    all_numbers = '0123456789'
    first_num = int(input("Enter a number you want to multiply: "))
    second_num = int(input("Enter how many attempts you want to make: "))
    count = 0

    while(second_num != 0):
        second_num = second_num - 1
        if('0' in str(first_num) and '1' in str(first_num) and \
        '2' in str(first_num) and '3' in str(first_num) and \
        '4' in str(first_num) and '5' in str(first_num) and \
        '6' in str(first_num) and '7' in str(first_num) and \
        '8' in str(first_num) and '9' in str(first_num)):
            break
        first_num = first_num * 2
        count = count + 1

    print(str(count))
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why first convert the input to an `int` and then convert to a `str` for the condition? Why not keep the input as a string, and then converse to an `int` when you need the value as an integer?

Comment: Can you write a sample input and a sample output please?

Comment: Good point, I'll change them. I just put int to input by habit

Comment: sample input: first_num = 1 and second_num = 1000. Output should be 68

Answer (score 1):

Make a `set` out of the digits of the numbers and compare them:

```
all_numbers = set("0123456789")
...
if all_numbers == set(str(first_num)):
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
all_numbers = '0123456789'
first_num = int(input("Enter a number you want to multiply: "))
second_num = int(input("Enter how many attempts you want to make: "))
count = 0
#Loop thorough the 0 to 9 and check 
#Please fix the indentation as I am writing it directly 


while(second_num != 0):
    second_num = second_num - 1
    flag = 0
    for i in range(10):
        if str(i) not in str(first_num):
            flag=1
            break
    if flag==0:
        break



    first_num = first_num * 2
    count = count + 1

print(str(count))
```